# Is there a model or algorithm to improve digital drawings?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

given a bad drawing, the algorithm should deform the edges of the bad drawing and fill them with color so that it looks more like a learned character.

the entry would be a very poorly made drawing of a character and the algorithm or model should improve it so that it looks like the character.

[image]

There is a publication or algorithm that explains how to do this?

Comment: "learned character"? So does it mean that the pictures on the right are also input? (During the learning phase?) You need to be specific about this.

Comment: BTW, not sure if stats is the best SE site to ask this. You could try these:
1) https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/
2) https://dsp.stackexchange.com/
3) https://ai.stackexchange.com/
4) and of course, stackoverflow.com. Not specialized at this, but there are many people from the field.

Comment: suppose that the images on the right were generated by the ai, but a set of similar images were used in the training phase
  and the ai learned the geometry of the character, it is as if I drew the character badly and gave it to the expert artist who created the character that redraws me improved.

Comment: see pix2pix paper

Comment: mmm are you sure ?, as I understand pix2pix seems to map one image to another. that is, it does not perform deformation, I think

Comment: deformation is a type of mapping